# Boot problem in ubuntu precise pangolin 12.04

Tags: boot-failure

After updating the updates,ubuntu refuse to reboot?please help?
how i can recover ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Please edit your question to describe in detail exactly what *does* happen when you try to boot. What do you see? Are there any error messages? You should also include information about the updates you installed--did you just *update* a pre-existing 12.04 LTS system, or did you start out with a previous version of Ubuntu and *upgrade* from that to 12.04 LTS? (If the latter, what version did you start out with?) Also, what is the make and model of your computer and of your video card?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. 
Solution: Reinstall / and when updating first time uncheck everything related to wireless drivers, xorg & Compiz.
Worked for me.

DELL Inspiron
4gb (Pae Kernel)
ATI
BROADCOM
Good Luck